# Interaction from .NET application with a Google Chrome extension

Tags: .net, google-chrome-extension, ipc

I have a question regarding browser remote controlling. My primary goal is to read out all open tab URLs from Google Chrome and also focus a tab if a matching URL is found and reload the current page. All this stuff is invoked from the native application (not from Chrome to the native application.

Currently, I've tried to do with Win32-API stuff (FindWindowEx, ...), new .NET Automation stuff, but this just gives me nothing (the former) or only the URL of the current tab (the latter).

So I thought - based on research - it would be the best idea to write a Google Chrome Extension and interact this way. The sad thing about this is: NPAPI extensions are no longer supported and only the JavaScript-kinda stuff is supported right now.

I then tried to communicate using nativeMessaging but I can't get things to work (never gets executed somehow) and the documentation part about this is -censored-.

This leads me to the question if things are even possible and if yes, how are they possible?

Host application, registered in the registry (Windows):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string message = "{\"text\": \"My response\"}";
    byte[] length = BitConverter.GetBytes(message.Length);
    foreach (byte b in length)
    {
        Console.Write((char)b);
    }
    Console.Write(message);
}
```

Manifest for the host application

```
{
  "name": "My.ChromeHost",
  "description": "This extension is used for browser interaction with My App.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Company AG\\My Product\\My.ChromeHost.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://bejoalmncckddamdhnfjafipbgflolmk"
  ]
}
```

Manifest for extension

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My App",
  "description": "This extension is used for browser interaction with My App.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
// sending a message to the app (altough I need it vice versa)
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("My.ChromeHost");
port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
port.postMessage({ "text": "My request" });

function onNativeMessage(message) {
    alert("Received message: <b>" + JSON.stringify(message) + "</b>");
}

function onDisconnected() {
    alert("Failed to connect: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    port = null;
}
```

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm trying the same approach, following the [somewhat limited documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging). Wondering whether the registry is not set up correctly, or the manifest, or the app can't be called. Quite unclear 'where' it can't connect.

Comment: Some [relevant info on Chromium extensions Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/0tpZnA0qezY).

Comment: @StevenJeuris Yes and no. I managed to do establish a connection to my native application, but not using native messaging. I switched to SignalR to communicate. A self-hosted SignalR host is running in my application and the extension acts as client which registers once it is started. Then, IPC is possible from both sides and this is enough for my requirements.

Comment: I might end up doing the same. I presume you used a background page rather than an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) in that scenario?

Comment: @StevenJeuris Correct, I'm using a background page. I can share my stuff if you're going the same way.

Comment: No need, I can see how that would work. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I [asked some more specific related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22963801/590790), which might interest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do establish a connection to my native application, but not using native messaging. I switched to SignalR to communicate. A self-hosted SignalR host is running in my application and the extension acts as client which registers once it is started. Then, IPC is possible from both sides and this is enough for my requirements.

**Update**: Upon request, a small sample application is located here:

http://tooldesign.ch/pub/SignalRChrome.zip

Please check https://developer.chrome.com/extensions for information on how to develop, pack and distribute the Chrome extension. This is not included in my sample project because of the private keys.

Comment: Hey would you happen to be able to zip up your project(s) and post it here? I'm looking to do something similar to what you did and would like to tinker with your project to see if it can do what i'm looking to do?

Comment: I'm not allowed to upload the original project, but I can make a sample application based on it.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Is there anyway to get around the limit of how much you can send and receive? It tells me the length is too large to send.

Comment: I never had such large messages, but do you get the error in the extension or your server?

Comment: The server page saying it's too large of a request string.

Comment: Could you write a simple html page to go along with this that shows how to send and receive calls to/from the C# program?