# Manage browser extensions through .net

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome-extension

I want to manage mozilla and chrome extensions through .net. To be more spesific I would like my extension to work on chrome and if a condition is met I'd like to open that page in mozilla. Is this possible?

So far I made a chrome extension it is working without any problem. But I'm stuck at "condition met"

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636130/interaction-from-net-application-with-a-google-chrome-extension